# HDFS file locality / replica placement hints

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Is there any way to tell HDFS where I'd like to get file replicas during certain file creation? OK, I understand this could be just hint and it is not guaranteed in any case. Thank you.

Why I need this? I have MapReduce job (actually chain of them) and as I have control over input splits locality I'd like previous job reducers to account next job mappers 'most probable' location. This is one of alternatives how to solve my problem. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible with [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385). It allows you to write Java code that specifies how HDFS should allocate replicas of blocks of a file.

HTH

Comment: OK, this is probably direction with biggest potential. Idea is accepted but complexity is too high to do it right now. Actually RESOLVED/DELAYED.